# Active Choice Reactive Reference Parameter not working in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to use Active Choice Reactive Reference Parameter with Jenkinsfile, but I did not get any option to use with Jenkinsfile.
tried to use something like that

```
**properties([
parameters([
    [$class: 'ChoiceParameter',
        choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
        description: 'Select the Env Name from the Dropdown List',
        filterLength: 1,
        filterable: true,
        name: 'Env',
        randomName: 'choice-parameter-5631314439613978',
        script: [
            $class: 'GroovyScript',
            fallbackScript: [
                classpath: [],
                sandbox: false,
                script:
                    'return[\'Could not get Env\']'
            ],
            script: [
                classpath: [],
                sandbox: false,
                script:
                    'return["Dev","QA","Stage","Prod"]'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter',
        choiceType: 'PT_CHECKBOX',
        description: 'Select Servers',
        filterLength: 1,
        filterable: true,
        name: 'Server',
        randomName: 'choice-parameter-5631314456178619',
        referencedParameters: 'Env',
        script: [
            $class: 'GroovyScript',
            fallbackScript: [
                classpath: [],
                sandbox: false,
                script:
                    'return[\'Could not get Environment from Env Param\']'
            ],
            script: [
                classpath: [],
                sandbox: false,
                script:
                    ''' if (Env.equals("Dev")){
                            return["devaaa001","devaaa002","devbbb001","devbbb002","devccc001","devccc002"]
                        }
                        else if(Env.equals("QA")){
                            return["qaaaa001","qabbb002","qaccc003"]
                        }
                        else if(Env.equals("Stage")){
                            return["staaa001","stbbb002","stccc003"]
                        }
                        else if(Env.equals("Prod")){
                            return["praaa001","prbbb002","prccc003"]
                        }
                    '''
            ]
        ]
    ]
])
```

getting error:

> The properties section has been renamed as of version 0.8. Use options

Could someone help on this?
This will be appreciated.